# passar uma struct utilizando extern C em uma .dll c++

Tags: c, c++, struct, dll, extern

Possuo uma função que vem de uma .lib que me retorna um struct

```
tabela GSTV(vector<double> inpA, vector<double> inpB);
```

esse struct é definido da seguinte forma:

```
struct tabela {

    vector<int> Z;
    vector<double> F;
    vector<double> S;
    vector<double> Y;


};
```

Porém estou transformando esse .lib em uma .dll com `extern "C"`

Quando tenho para um vetor eu costumo fazer:

```
vector<int> GSTV(vector<double> inpA, vector<double> inpB);
```

passar a ser

```
extern "C" MINHADLL_API void GSTV( vector<double> inpA, vector<double> inpB, vector<int> &GSTV_ans);
```

E assim pelo argumento eu gero o meu vetor, entretanto para um struct isso não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que era apenas preciso declarar um `extern "C"` da `struct` no cabeçalho da `.dll` também:

```
extern "C" struct tabela;
```

dessa forma pelo que entendi ele converte a struct da `.lib` original e funciona corretamente o código.